# Connect to localhost from remote server

Tags: php, soap, localhost, soap-client

I need to connect to a local port (8046) to execute a service that is installed in the local computer. I have no problem if I start a local server like Wamp or PHPDesktop, but what if I created a Linux server (on the same network) and I would like to call the service? Is there any way to do that?

I tried to obtain the computer name and connect to `compname:8046`, but it is not working; any suggestions?

```
$xml='---req--'
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8046';

$post_data = array(
    "xml" => $xml,
);

$stream_options = array(
    'http' => array(
       'method'  => 'POST',
       'header'  => "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8",
       'content' => urldecode(http_build_query($post_data)),
       'timeout' => 12000,
    ),
);

$context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response = @file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
```

Comment: On local Lan, if one of those pc are linux... use the ip to call "localhost" not the pc name

Comment: Hi Marco.. only the server have linux installed.. all the other PCs are windows xp or 7.. I tried to call computerip:8046 but is not working...

Comment: @MarcoMura I search and I found something like cross domain.. do you think it could help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the IP address of the computer you are trying to connect to, or if you are running a DNS server on your local network then you could use the name. Then you would just access it like `http://000.000.000.000:8046` obviously replacing the `0`s with the actual IP on your network.

If you were trying to access this computer from a remote one, say a hosting account somewhere then you would need to configure your router to forward port `8046` to the proper computer on the network.